# Server 500 while starting up a new php-laravel project on linux

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have zero php experience, but need to fire up an existing application that I have cloned (which is supposed to be functional), to test it quickly. I think I'm pretty close to have it working.

If I run `php artisan serve`:

```
[franck@franck-vee appliweb]$ php artisan serve
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Tue Sep 28 13:31:56 2021] PHP 8.0.10 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
[Tue Sep 28 13:32:00 2021] 127.0.0.1:34716 Accepted
[Tue Sep 28 13:32:00 2021] 127.0.0.1:34716 Closing
[Tue Sep 28 13:32:00 2021] 127.0.0.1:34722 Accepted
[Tue Sep 28 13:32:00 2021] 127.0.0.1:34722 [200]: GET /favicon.ico
[Tue Sep 28 13:32:00 2021] 127.0.0.1:34722 Closing
```

If I visit localhost:8000 however, I get [image], which seems to be a Laravel 500 error page. So I am serving, which is good, but the app isn't really running.

Installations steps I have done:

- clone the git repo for the source coe & cd to project root
- install php, composer, npm (for javascript) & verify they work on my system (all return valid version on my system)
- run npm install, composer install from project root to install the content of composer.lock, package.lock, which are present at project root
- `php artisan serve` from project root

After I get the 500 server error, if I look at the logs (in storage/logs/laravel.logs), I find the following stack trace:

```
[2021-09-28 17:40:49] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Encryption\\MissingAppKeyException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php:79)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(263): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}()
#1 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(81): tap()
#2 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(60): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->key()
#3 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(32): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->parseKey()
#4 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(829): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}()
#5 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(714): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#6 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#7 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(652): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#8 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(826): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#9 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(987): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#10 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(907): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass()
#11 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(868): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies()
#12 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(714): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#13 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#14 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(652): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#15 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(826): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#16 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(156): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#17 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#18 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(695): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#19 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(670): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#20 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(636): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#21 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#22 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#23 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#24 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#25 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#26 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#27 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#28 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#29 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#30 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#31 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#32 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#33 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle()
#34 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#35 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()
#36 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#37 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#38 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#39 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#40 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/server.php(21): require_once('...')
#41 {main}
"} 
[2021-09-28 17:40:49] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Encryption\\MissingAppKeyException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php:79)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(263): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}()
#1 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(81): tap()
#2 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(60): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->key()
#3 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(32): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->parseKey()
#4 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(829): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}()
#5 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(714): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#6 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#7 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(652): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#8 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(826): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#9 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(987): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#10 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(907): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass()
#11 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(868): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies()
#12 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(714): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#13 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#14 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(652): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#15 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(826): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#16 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(205): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#17 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(179): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminateMiddleware()
#18 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminate()
#19 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/server.php(21): require_once('...')
#20 {main}
"} 
[2021-09-28 17:42:09] production.ERROR: file_get_contents(/home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/.env): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): file_get_contents(/home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/.env): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php:96)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php(96): file_get_contents()
#2 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php(80): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\KeyGenerateCommand->writeNewEnvironmentFileWith()
#3 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php(45): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\KeyGenerateCommand->setKeyInEnvironmentFile()
#4 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\KeyGenerateCommand->handle()
#5 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#6 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#7 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#8 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(611): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#9 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#10 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(256): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute()
#11 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run()
#12 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(971): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run()
#13 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(290): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand()
#14 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(166): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun()
#15 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(92): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run()
#16 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run()
#17 /home/franck/Documents/PRO/foobar/appliweb/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#18 {main}
"}
```

I have found a few references that note that `php artisan key:generate` should generate such a key for me & solve the error. However, I then get another error if I run that last command:

```
[franck@franck-vee appli-assurance]$ php artisan key:generate

   ErrorException 

  file_get_contents(/home/franck/Documents/PRO/kbrs/appli-assurance/.env): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php:96
     92▕     {
     93▕         file_put_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath(), preg_replace(
     94▕             $this->keyReplacementPattern(),
     95▕             'APP_KEY='.$key,
  ➜  96▕             file_get_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath())
     97▕         ));
     98▕     }
     99▕ 
    100▕     /**

      +16 vendor frames 
  17  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I'm starting to think I'm missing something key upstream. Am I supposed to have some sort of .env file in the project? There are none coming in from the git repo. Could it be that some environement files/variables are not present? Or are there additional artisan/composer commands I need to be running before I can think of spinning it up?

Comment: Laravel is a framework and allows you infinite ways to assemble your application and cause 500 errors. It's impossible to say what's wrong in your application. Set a breakpoint and debug through the code.

Comment: It's impossible unless one actually reads the question. I provided the logs from that error. Ugur had it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you don't have an `.env` file at your root directory. You need to create an `.env` file which can be copied from `.env.example`.

After that you can run `php artisan key:generate` and it should work fine.

Comment: Yes indeed. I mean I get that the .env files aren't generally committed, but it would still somewhat expect at last a note to that effect (if it is NEEDED for the app to run). THanks a bunch

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions *"fire up an existing application that I have cloned (which is supposed to be functional)"* - Sounds like whoever you cloned this from didn't leave you valid instructions on running a Laravel application  This is from the documentation: *"In a fresh Laravel installation, the root directory of your application will contain a .env.example file that defines many common environment variables. During the Laravel installation process, this file will automatically be copied to .env."*; this was missed for your project. Glad you got it working regardless though!

Comment: Ha. I actually received it as a zip file (not from original dev). So yes, technically I cloned it, after I create a repo for it :| - the joys of coding for hire with friends from all over the world!